# Undefined Index error while uploading a file using php

Tags: php, undefined-index

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(../uploads/IMG_23052014_111633.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\test.co\getfile.php on line 8
>   Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\wamp\tmp\php9EF8.tmp' to '../uploads/IMG_23052014_111633.png' in C:\wamp\www\test.co\getfile.php on line 8

how to get rid of it?
HTML code:

```
<form action="getfile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" ><br>
Type (or select) Filename: <input type="file" name="uploadFile">
<input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Process Uploaded File</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadFile'] ['tmp_name'], 
"../uploads/{$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']}")
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: enctype attribute is missing in your form

Comment: @AmitThakur what do you mean so what should i do?

Comment: Check this question for more info on - 
[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Comment: @AmitThakur i did add it it does not change the error

Comment: Did the question marked by Rizier help you?

Comment: @AmitThakur honstly it might help but iam new to php so even if the answer is there icant implement it iwant some one to answer this question by using exactly the same code iam using and changing it to the right way

Comment: This post might help you- http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php **Thank you Tizag!**

Comment: @AmitThakur nope i did every thing and i get this >There was an error uploading the file, please try again!

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your filesystem, check the folder permission..  A few days ago I pasted a multiple file upload script => https://eval.in/298954 hope this helps!

Comment: There you need to change just 1 single line => **$path="path/";** to **$path="your_directory_and_then_a_slash/"**